# GDB: running cpp process debugging without symbols

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

Linux system running an application. This application is a cpp binary without any debug symbols. Some how this application using 100% cpu. Would like to debug why it is running infinitely. If I stop and replace the binary with debug symbols, the issue may not be reproducible.

So, running the same application with debug symbols in another environment. Here it is running fine.

Can I compare them (with and without debug symbols binaries) and deduct what is the problem using GDB.

Comment: A profiler might help you narrow down the problem site. You probably won't get the function name, but you should get an address you can work back to the problem function with a memory map if you configure the linker to provide one.

Comment: Great. Can you explain with more details using some example.

Comment: Debug symbols don't need to be built into the running binary to debug, you just need to load the binary with the debug symbols into gcc

Comment: @AlanBirtles, Can you provide more details with an example?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

Answer (score 2):

> This application is a cpp binary without any debug symbols

You *don't need* any debug symbols to understand where it is spending time, you just need the application to not be *fully-stripped* (most binaries aren't).

Use `perf record -p $pid` to collect CPU profile, then `perf report` to analyse it.

If the application *is* fully stripped, you can still use `perf record` to collect program counter values, then `perf record --symfs ...` to point it to unstripped copy of the application. Documentation [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html).

Beware: both stripped and unstripped copies must be built with *exactly* the same build flags, or you'll get garbage. Best practice is to *always* save unstripped copy as part of the build process.

Comment: But the application environment is restricted to take perf reports. Any other ways solve this using the GDB only.

Comment: @Kranthi Restricted in what way?